# casting data type in function arguments?

Tags: php

Does anyone know why it fails?

```
<?php 
function data((string)$data)
{
echo $data;

}

data(123);
```

Here is the error:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING_CAST, expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE in x.php on line 3

Comment: you can't cast datatype this way, but you may want to use function data(string $data) - typehinting if you use PHP 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your are trying to do is called: **Type Hinting**.

That is allowing a function or class method to dictate the type of argument it recieves.

Static type hinting was only introduced in PHP7 so using a version greater than that you can achieve whay you want with the following:

```
<?php

function myFunction(string $string){
    echo $string;
}
```

Now any non string argument passed to myFunction will throw an error.

Comment: it doesn't throw any error in php7 if you dont pass a sring,it works

Answer (score 0):

You cant cast when parsing arguments to the function. Do it inside the function

```
function data($data)
{
echo (string) $data;

}

data(123);
```

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
<?php 
function data(string $data) {
    echo $data;
}

data(123);
```

But you have to use PHP7. I have tested that code with PHP7.

```
Output: string(3) "123"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to typecast like this instead you can hint the type of your argument using the concept of type hinting read more about [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

```
<?php 
function data(string $data)
{
echo $data;

}

data(123);
```

or if you are fine with this you can use like this

```
<?php 
function data($data)
{
echo (string) $data;

}

data(123);
```